# Stop infinite loop in self-referencing models

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a little utility which allows me to populate data models with a number of records.
I used python faker to set the values for each field based on their field-type.

What I do next, is that I use `model._meta.get_fields` to extract all the fields, remove all `Rel` types, and then populate non-relational fields with the correct values. For relational fields (where `.re_relation = True`) I follow the relation to the related model, then do the same for that model as well until I reach a model where there is no more relations to other models. Then create instances for each model.

Basically a recursive process.

My problem is with self-referencing models which cause an infinite loop. I thought of setting these instances to null but what about instances where null is set to False?

Is there any clean way to handle situations like this? I couldn't find anything on the net or stackoverflow.

ps: the code is pretty long so I didn't post anything. But I can if it's necessary.

Comment: providing the code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often when there's the possibility of an infinite loop, you can prevent that by setting a counter which if is reached, breaks out of the loop.

In your case, you can explicitly check if the relation references the same model and then, prevent it from following the relation.

Moreover, a model that is referencing itself, should allow for the relationship to be null.